# explain this code

Tags: javascript

I need to understand what does the code do
this page is on my blog and I have not created it

```
var u = location.href, h = u.substr(u.indexOf('#') + 1).split('&'), t, r;
try {
  t = h[0] === '..' ? parent.parent : parent.frames[h[0]];
  r = t.gadgets.rpc.receive;
} catch (e) {
}
r && r(h);
```

location of the page is
http://roadtoheavenisnothere.blogspot.com/rpc_relay.html

Comment: looks like some minified code.... what do you want?

Comment: What parts of it don't you understand?  The first line creates some variables, the try block looks for a method called `t.gadgets.rpc.receive` and absorbs an exception (bad practice) and the last line calls `r()` if it was assigned in the try block.

Comment: It's not that much code. Just rewrite it to make it do what you need and make it easy to read.

Comment: was on a page on my blog. I did not create it(probably is on all blogs or was created by a gadget on my blog).was checking if there is a vulnerability through this page on my blog

Comment: I actually wanted to know how does this script affects my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. define variables u, h, t, and r locally
2. set u to be the current URL
3. set h to be all of the `&` delineated values *after* the `#`.
4. if h[0] = '..' then t = parent.parent otherwise t = parent.frames[h[0]]
   (this means the property h[0] of the frames object on parent)
5. if t has property t.gadgets.rpc.receive; then set that to r
6. if r, then call r on h.
7. ...?
8. [Profit](http://www.southparkstudios.com/clips/151040/the-underpants-business)

Comment: +1, but suggest an addition: 7. ???, 8. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

It's accessing a frame based on the hash portion of the url up until the first `&`. So everything between `#` and `&` in the url. It then gets something called an rpc gadget from the frame (I have no idea what that object is) and sets a variable called r to the receive function of that object. The if that function exists, it calls that function on the whole array of everything in the url after the first `#` split into sections by `&`.

I hope that explains it well enough.